# Chrome DOM Refresh while editing HTML on inspect element

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, google-chrome, dom

how does chrome handle edit as html option in inspect element view?
if you click edit as html and remove a jquery-ui directive, lets say ui-sortable from the div, dragging functionality disables as expected. But the page did not get reloaded?
 How could DOM understand that the preloaded javascript function got off.

I am asking this because, if you double click on the class section and erase class by hand, then div still drags, DOM doesnt understand it.
So how can edit as html option refreshes DOM without feeling it to user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you edit as HTML, the entire node that you are editing is removed and reinserted into the DOM. Hence your draggable events are not bound to the new node which has been inserted. When you double click and change an attribute, only that attribute is modified, the actual DOM element stays the same.